# C++ variables in different block

Tags: c++, scope

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int a {1};

int main()
{
    int a {2};

    {
        int a {3};
        cout << ::a << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the first output is `1`, it's the value of a that defined before function `main()`

so is there any way to output the second `a` that defined in function `main()` in the inner block ?
thanks!

Comment: [**TL;DR**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047621/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-value-of-a-local-variable-that-has-become-hidden-in#comment8428868_7047655).

Comment: @StoryTeller I think the post you tagged is different to this.

Comment: @codekaizer - It's not. It's the exact same problem. The only difference is the more fleshed out comparison to the variable at global scope

Comment: @StoryTeller, the answers seems a little bit vague - like it's unsupported or inaccessible. So would that mean my answer is wrong?

Comment: @codekaizer - The answers all point out that there is no direct language support, and present workarounds (the good ones anyway). I don't see why yours would be wrong. It's an acceptable workaround. I also think it would belong to the duplicate just as much as it can belong here (which is why I firmly believe in the other post being a good dupe candidate).

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks for clarifying about the *workaround*.

Answer (score 1):

> so is there any way to output the second `a` that defined in function
>   `main()` in the *inner* block ?

`a{2}` and `a{3}` are both in [*block-scope*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.block).

Thus, `a{3}` [shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621785/shadowing-variables) `a{2}` in the *inner*-block.

To output the `a{2}` you just need to move the [*point-of-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.pdecl) of `a{3}`.

```
int a {2};

{
    cout << ::a << endl;
    cout << a << endl; // a{2} will be used here
                       // since a{3} is not defined here yet.
    int a {3};
    cout << a << endl; // a{3} will be used here
                       // since it's already defined at this point
}
```